# Parse String to Long using a specified locale (sv) and NumberFormat

Tags: java, string, parsing, locale

I tried to parse a string (14 123) to a long in java using Swedish locale using this code:

```
String longString = "14 123"
NumberFormat swedishNumberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("sv"));
System.out.println(swedishNumberFormat.parse(longString).longValue());
```

The output of this code is 14 (it should be 14123). As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252824/java-whats-the-difference-between-the-sv-and-sv-se-locale) I tried with both the sv and sv_SE locale but this time the result was identical in both cases.

According to http://www.localeplanet.com/java/sv/index.html and http://www.localeplanet.com/java/sv-SE/index.html the grouping separator in both cases is a space() so why does the string to long parsing not handle a, for the locale, properly formatted double value stored as string?

Comment: So a bug in the Swedish locale in Java?

Comment: To me this question and answer below is better than one marked as related. I do not think this question  should be closed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Swedish, as French too, needs a hard. non-breaking space.

```
longString = longString.replace(' ', '\u00a0');
```

Cumbersome.

Comment: @GameDroids yes quite an utterly misleading design decision to use a non-breaking space as grouping separator. Maybe they wanted to prevent word-breaks on `format` generated numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Could you  try

Parse that string with manually set up DecimalFormat. Construct it, configure to have *setGroupingUsed(true*), *setDecimalSymbols* with your own *DecimalFormatSymbols*.

```
DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat();
df.setGroupingSize(3);
df.setGroupingUsed(true);
DecimalFormatSymbols newSymbols=new DecimalFormatSymbols();
newSymbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(newSymbols);
df.parse(longString)
```

Second option is to debug your code see swedishNumberFormat instance  you have. inspect fields groupingSize, decimalFormatSymbols.groupingSeparators.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21216199/896249), you need to set whitespace as a seperator manually.

```
 try {
      String longString = "14 123";            
      DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat();  // instead of NumberFormat, use DecimalFormat
      DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(new Locale("sv", "SE"));
      symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');   // set the whitespace manually as grouping seperator
      decimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);           
      System.out.println(svSE.parse(longString)); 
  } catch (ParseException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(Playground.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }

    //> output is 14123
```

to be honest I am a little confused, but I think the *issue* is, that you need *formated strings* (apparently not every whitespace is the same here )

```
 try {
      long testNumber = 123987l; 
      NumberFormat swedishNumberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("sv")); 

      //here I format the number into a String
      String formatedString = swedishNumberFormat.format(testNumber);  
      System.out.println(formatedString);  // result: "123 987"

      // when parsing the formated String back into a number
      System.out.println(swedishNumberFormat.parse(formatedString));  // result: "123987"

      // but when parsing a non formated string like this one
      System.out.println(swedishNumberFormat.parse("123 987")); // result "123"
 } catch (ParseException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(Playground.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
```

Please correct me if I am wrong here or my example didn't work. I have no Idea why it does the things like this, but to avoid confusing situations like the above, you may want to set the separator manually.

**EDIT**

as Joop Eggen stated in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26255559/896249) the String needs to use a hard, non-breaking space (`'\u00a0'`) instead of a simple whitespace. That's the reason why my example returns "123" in the last line (I only used the normal whitespace).